# How to convert this Stored Procedure from SQL Server to Postgresql?

Tags: sql-server, postgresql

I'm migrating some SQL Server queries to Postgresql and I have some trouble with it. Here's the SQL Server query

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_GetReportOrder]
    @storeId int = 0,
    @startDate date,
    @endDate date
AS
BEGIN

            select 
                t.JournalId,
                t.OrderId,
                d.DayOfWeek,
                d.Date,
                s.StoreName,
                t.TransTime,
                isnull(c.CashierName,'') as CashierName,
                (select
                    case when sum(ti.Quantity) = 1 then
                        ti.ProductVariantName + ', '
                        else
                            ti.ProductVariantName + ' (' + Convert(nvarchar,sum(ti.Quantity)) + '), '
                    end
                    from fact_OrderItem ti
                    where ti.JournalId = t.JournalID and t.OrderID = ti.OrderID
                    group by ti.ProductVariantName
                    FOR xml path('')
                ) as Items,
                t.Collected
            from Fact_Order t
                inner join Dim_Date d on t.DateID = d.DateID 
                inner join Dim_Store s on s.StoreID = t.StoreID
                left outer join Dim_Cashier c on c.CashierID = t.CashierID
            where d.Date >= @startDate and d.Date <= @endDate
                and t.storeId = @storeId

END
```

i've tried this

```
select 
                t."JournalID",
                t."OrderID",
                d."DayOfWeek",
                d."Date",
                s."StoreName",
                t."TransTime",
                coalesce(c."CashierName",'') as CashierName,
                (select
                    case when sum(ti."Quantity") = 1 then
                        ti."ProductVariantName" || ', '
                        else
                            ti."ProductVariantName" || ' (' || sum(ti."Quantity") || '), '
                    end
                    from dbo."fact_OrderItem" ti
                    where ti."JournalId" = t."JournalID" and t."OrderID" = ti."OrderID"
                    group by ti."ProductVariantName"
                    FOR xml path('')
                ) as Items,
                t."Collected"
            from dbo."Fact_Order" t
                inner join dbo."Dim_Date" d on t."DateID" = d."DateID" 
                inner join dbo."Dim_Store" s on s."StoreID" = t."StoreID"
                left outer join dbo."Dim_Cashier" c on c."CashierID" = t."CashierID"
            where d."Date" >= '2018-01-01' and d."Date" <= '2020-01-01'
                and t."StoreID" = 1
```

it shows syntax error at or near "xml". i'm using postgre 10. i don't know xml path in postgre. anybody can help me?
sorry if my english is bad

Comment: Asking for a full rewrite of such a large proc is probably too broad for a single question.  Instead, it would help if you could focus on one particular problem you are facing.

Comment: take a look at [https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/functions-xml.html](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/functions-xml.html)

Comment: oke, thanks for the advice. btw i also put there what i'm facing. i don't know xml path in postgre. @TimBiegeleisen

Comment: i'm confused. what should i use? @Augustas